# How does SqlClient work in medium trust when

Tags: .net, security, cas, sqlclient

SocketPermission is not allowed and..
pinvoking is not allowed.

I'm wanting to make sure my provider can work in medium/partial trust scenarios but trying to understand SqlClient first.

It makes sense to me that if you had a custom permission class and the hosting provider included your custom permission class in the policy, then your library would essentially have full trust but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Call all .NET security experts.  Can someone explain how this works to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SqlClient has full trust because System.Data.dll is in the GAC ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134148/do-assemblies-placed-in-the-gac-gain-full-trust)). So code in SqlClient just needs to allow partially trusted callers and then do SqlClientPermission.Demand() in the appropriate methods. Also there are [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] attributes to allow p/invoke.